# EF6 code first multiple 1-to-many mapping issue / "Multiplicity" error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, database-design, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I am receiving the following error when attempting to create the database:

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> Interaction_CauseElement_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role
>   'Interaction_CauseElement_Source' in relationship
>   'Interaction_CauseElement'. Because the Dependent Role properties are
>   not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the
>   Dependent Role must be '*'.
>
> Interaction_EffectElement_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role
>   'Interaction_EffectElement_Source' in relationship
>   'Interaction_EffectElement'. Because the Dependent Role properties are
>   not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the
>   Dependent Role must be '*'.

I've seen this error in other Stack Overflow posts, but in the examples I found, the OP was trying for a 1-to-1 relationship in both directions between the tables. That is not what I am looking for.

Here is my model:

```
public class Element
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(64)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Interaction
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Index, Required]
    public int CauseID { get; set; }

    [Index, Required]
    public int EffectID { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(64)]
    public string Location { get; set; }    

    [ForeignKey("CauseID")]
    public virtual Element CauseElement { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("EffectID")]
    public virtual Element EffectElement { get; set; }
}
```

Items in the Elements table are unique. A pair of elements can interact with each other in any number of locations. The CauseID/EffectID pair is not going to be unique.

The only other place I am changing the model is in the `OnModelCreating` method. I had received this error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   'FK_dbo.Interactions_dbo.Elements_Cause' on table
>   'Interactions' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths.
>   Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other
>   FOREIGN KEY constraints. Could not create constraint. See previous
>   errors.

And had to create a cascade policy for the model. This code fixed that error:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    //Prevent cyclic cascade on elements table
    modelBuilder.Entity<Interaction>()
        .HasRequired(i => i.CauseElement)
        .WithRequiredDependent()
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Interaction>()
        .HasRequired(i => i.EffectElement)
        .WithRequiredDependent()
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

But then I received the cryptic "Multiplicity" error. It seems like it wants me to make `public virtual Element CauseElement` into a collection like `public virtual ICollection<Element> CauseElement`, but that would not properly model the relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. [This article on EntityFrameworkTutoral.net helped out.](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) Because I need TWO references from the `Interaction` class to the `Element` class, this relationship is too complex to model in EF with only the attributes.

I had to update the model and then use the fluent API to tell EF how to treat the relationships. I updated my model to the following:

```
public class Element
{
    public Element()
    {
        CauseElements = new List<Interaction>();
        EffectElements = new List<Interaction>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(64)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    #region Navigation

    public virtual ICollection<Interaction> CauseElements { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Interaction> EffectElements { get; set; }

    #endregion
}

public class Interaction
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Index]
    public int CauseID { get; set; }

    [Index]
    public int EffectID { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(64)]
    public string Location { get; set; }

    #region Navigation

    [ForeignKey("CauseID")]
    public virtual Element CauseElement { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("EffectID")]
    public virtual Element EffectElement { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

And in my DbContext class I used the fluent API to create the link between the `Interaction.CauseElement` and `Element.CauseElements` and which property was the foreign key for the `Interaction` table (and the same with the Effect relationship):

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    //Prevent cyclic cascade on elements table
    modelBuilder.Entity<Interaction>()
        .HasRequired(i => i.CauseElement)
        .WithRequiredDependent()
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Interaction>()
        .HasRequired(i => i.EffectElement)
        .WithRequiredDependent()
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    //Create the links between the element, the key, and the collection
    modelBuilder.Entity<Interaction>()
        .HasRequired<Element>(i => i.CauseElement)
        .WithMany(e => e.CauseElements)
        .HasForeignKey(i => i.CauseID);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Interaction>()
        .HasRequired<Element>(i => i.EffectElement)
        .WithMany(e => e.EffectElements)
        .HasForeignKey(i => i.EffectID);

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

It seems that Entity Framework tries to automatically infer the relationships between the tables when you have a simple 1-to-many relationship. If I removed `EffectElement` from the `Interaction` class (and `EffectElements` from `Element`), EF was able to create the relationship easily. But when I added it back, I received the error again.

Since that `Element` type showed up twice in the `Interaction` class, it didn't know how to create the relationship. I had to explicitly define it in the `OnModelCreating` method.

Answer (score 0):

You reversed the responsibilities of the "ForeignKey" attribute. It goes on the ID field, specifying the property for which it serves as the foreign key. You want something as below:

```
// To-One on Element 
[ForeignKey("Element")]
public int ElementId { get; set; }
public virtual Element Element { get; set; }
```

Also, this is actually a one-to-one relationship. A one-to-many relationship in this case would be:

```
// To-Many on Element 
public virtual ICollection<Element> Elements{ get; set; }
```

Comment: Ok, I was thinking that since one element can be in many places in the interactions table that it would be considered 1-to-many, but you're saying it would be 1-to-many if I was linking, say Element.ID to Interactions.CauseID. Going, as I am, from Interaction.CauseID to Element.ID it is a 1-to-1. I got it.

Comment: I updated my code per your suggestion, but it didn't work. I received the exact same error. Please see the update on my question.

Comment: I figured out the problem. I posted my solution.